# An explicit reconstruction of a matrix from its minors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry, exterior-algebra, inverse-problems

$\newcommand{\End}{\operatorname{End}}$
$\newcommand{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}$
$\newcommand{\Cof}{\operatorname{cof}}$

Let $V$ be a $d$-dimensional **real** vector space. ($d \ge 4$). Fix an **odd integer** $2 \le k \le d-2$. Define
$H_{>k}=\{ A \in \End(V) \mid \operatorname{rank}(A) > k 
\}$. Consider the map
$$
\psi:H_{>k} \to \End(\bigwedge^k V) \, \,, \, \, \psi(A)=\bigwedge^{k}A.
$$

$\psi$ is a smooth injective immersion.

> **Question:** Is there an explicit formula for $\psi^{-1}$?

*Comments:*

1. Since $\operatorname{rank}(\bigwedge^kA) = \binom {\operatorname{rank}(A)}{k} $, we might start by considering each rank separately.
2. The limitation $k$ is odd is not essential. When $k$ is even, $\psi(A)=\psi(B)$ implies $A=\pm B$ (assuming $A,B \in H_{>k}$), so the inverse is well-defined up to a sign. In fact, the following more general property holds:

Let $V$ be a vector space over an arbitrary field $F$. Then, for $A,B \in H_{>k}$, $\psi(A)=\psi(B)$ iff $A=\lambda B$ when $\lambda^k=1$. So, we can ask the question in this more general setting:

> Is there an explicit formula, which given an element in $\text{Image }(\psi)$, produces a source element?

---

Part of the problem is that we do not have a closed-form description of $\text{Image }(\psi)$, and it is clear that in general we don't expect $\psi^{-1} $ to have a continuous extension to all $\End(\bigwedge^k V)$ (or even to the space of all endomorphisms of rank bigger than $k$, which is where $\text{Image }(\psi)$ lies, but I am not sure about that.)

*I am OK with a formula which uses an inner product and orientation structures. Even though we don't need them in order to define $\psi$, they somehow appear naturally when trying to compute $\psi^{-1}$.*

Indeed, in the special case $k=d-1$, $\psi(A) \in \text{GL}(\bigwedge^{d-1}V)$ can be identified with the cofactor matrix of $A$. (The identification is done using the Hodge dual $\star:\bigwedge^{d-1}V \to V$).

Then we have $ \Cof(\Cof A)=(\det A)^{d-2}A$. Now, if $\Cof A=B$, then $\Cof B=(\det A)^{d-2}A$, and $\det(B)=(\det(A))^{d-1}$.

Since $k=d-1$ is odd, we can take the (unique) $ d-1 $-th root, so $(\det(B))^{\frac{1}{d-1}}=\det(A)$.

Thus,

$$ A=(\Cof)^{-1} B=(\det B)^{\frac{2-d}{d-1}} \Cof B  $$
gives the formula for $\psi^{-1}$.

Trying to generalize this derivation using the Hodge dual for general $k$ seems to hit a wall.

Comment: I imagine there might also be a special case at $k=d/2$ 
because $\bigwedge^k V$ is nearly the same as $\bigwedge^k V^*$
so the map could be 2:1.

Comment: For any fixed $k,d$, if $k$ is relatively prime to $d$, letting $l$ be an first inverse of $k$ mod $d$, then there exists explicitly definable maps (using just the vector space structure) making $V \otimes \det V^{\frac{lk-1}{d}}$ a summand of $(\wedge^k V)^{\otimes l })$. One can apply these maps and then multiply by $\det B^{ - \frac{lk-1}{d k}}$ to recover $A$, at least in the full rank case. This generalizes your cofactor example. The hodge star may be a red herring, as you can just as well write $A = (\det B)^{\frac{2-d}{d-1}} \bigwedge^{d-1} B$.

Comment: @WillSawin I think your method could be generalized; it seems based on decomposition of composition of Schur functors (where the first Schur functor is the $k$th wedge power), which could be done more generally.

Comment: @user44191 The problem is starting from Schur functors invariant under a certain scalar, you can only obtain Schur functors invariant under that scalar.

Comment: @WillSawin If I've understood correctly, that's where taking roots should be helpful, similar to how roots were used to get the determinant of $A$ in the example given, right?

Comment: @user44191 Yes, the issue is what you take roots of. For instance if you take roots of det B you want to end up with an integer power of det A and not some other power, which won't be a Schur functor at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that $kl=d+1$.

Then I claim that $V \otimes \det V$ appears as a summand of $\left( \bigwedge^k V\right)^{\otimes l}$ with multiplicity $l-1$.

The maps $\left( \bigwedge^k V\right)^{\otimes l} \to V \otimes \det V$ are easier to write down - the $i$'th maps sends $$ (v_{1,1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{1,k}) \otimes \dots \otimes (v_{l,1}\wedge \dots \wedge v_{l,k})$$ to $$\sum_{j=1}^{k} (-1)^{ il+j} v_{i,j} \otimes (v_{1,1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{1,k} \wedge v_{2,1} \dots \wedge v_{i,j-1} \wedge v_{i,j+1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{l,k})$$

and we have the relation that the $l$ maps sum to zero. The reverse maps are similar, except that the $i$th map is a sum over all the ways to divide the $kl$ vectors evenly into $l$ boxes, with the first vector in the $i$'th box.

Now if we have an endomorphism of $\wedge^k V$, we can let it act on $\left( \bigwedge^k V \right)^{\otimes l}$, compose with one of these maps on each side, and obtain an endomorphism of $V$. If we apply this to an element of $GL(V)$, we get the individual element back, times its determinant, times some fixed scalar depending on the choice of map. We can divide by the scalar and by the $\frac{1}{ {d-1 \choose k-1}}$ power of the determinant of the endomorphism of $\bigwedge^k V$ to obtain the original matrix exactly.

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting. I still have some questions about this: (1) Why did you need the $il$ in the sign factor $(-1)^{il+j}$? If you only put $(-1)^j$ your maps would still be well-defined, right? (I guess this is related to your claim that the sum of all the $l$ maps is zero?) (2) If I followed correctly, then when you start with an element $A \in \text{GL}(V)$, and you finish with an endomorphism of $V \otimes \det V $, which is given explicitly by...

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^{k} (-1)^{ il+j} v_{i,j} \otimes (v_{1,1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{1,k} \wedge v_{2,1} \dots \wedge v_{i,j-1} \wedge v_{i,j+1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{l,k}) \to   $ $\det A \sum_{j=1}^{k} (-1)^{ il+j} Av_{i,j} \otimes (v_{1,1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{1,k} \wedge v_{2,1} \dots \wedge v_{i,j-1} \wedge v_{i,j+1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{l,k})$. How do you recover $A$ from that? Do you use some identification $\det V \simeq \mathbb{R}$, and then use the fact $V \times \mathbb{R}$ is canonically isomorphic to $V$?

Comment: @AsafShachar (1) Exactly, without that it would be a signed sum that vanishes. (2). Yes, that's the idea, except because the identification $\det V \cong \mathbb R$ is not canonical, you have to divide by $\det A$, which is equivalent to dividing by some power of the determinant of the original endomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. I am still not sure though how do you verify that the resulting endomorphism would not not depend on the identification $\det V \cong \mathbb{R}$ you choose. ($\det A$ is well-defined anyway as a real number, without any choice of identification needed, since $\bigwedge^d A:\bigwedge^d V \to \bigwedge^d V$ is an endomorphism of a one dimensional vector space ). So, after you divide by $\det A$ you obtain the map $\sum_{j=1}^{k} (-1)^{ il+j} v_{i,j} \otimes (v_{1,1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{1,k} \wedge v_{2,1} \dots \wedge v_{i,j-1} \wedge v_{i,j+1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{l,k}) \to $

Comment: $ \sum_{j=1}^{k} (-1)^{ il+j} Av_{i,j} \otimes (v_{1,1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{1,k} \wedge v_{2,1} \dots \wedge v_{i,j-1} \wedge v_{i,j+1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{l,k}) $, then you need to identify.   Also, do we know ${d-1 \choose k-1}$ is odd? (We need this to recover unambiguously $\det A$, and not only up to sign.)  Finally, I am not sure what exactly do you mean by saying that  $V \otimes \det V$ appears as a summand of $\left( \bigwedge^k V\right)^{\otimes l}$ *with multiplicity* $l-1$? Does that somehow mean that the *only* relation between your $l$ maps is that their sum vanishes?

Comment: I am sorry for all these questions... I tried to read a little about Schur functors (I understood from the comments they are related). Do you have any "inspiration" for your construction based on some insights from representation theory ?

Comment: @AsafShachar (1) Changing the isomorphism corresponds to multiplying by a scalar on the left and another scalar on the right, which fixes the matrix. (2) If it's not odd but $k$ is odd there's a way to get around it, by extracting $\det V^k$ from the $d$th tensor power of $\bigwedge^k V$. (3) Yes, I mean that this is the only relation. I am just thinking of the multiplicity of the irreducible representations.

Comment: (4) I have a couple insights. First, the Tannakian idea. Any representation of $GL_d$ can be written as a summand of a tensor product of $\wedge^k V$ and its dual if and only if, viewed as a representation of $GL_d(\mathbb C)$, its kernel is contained in the kernel of $\wedge^k V$. So we can calculate the action on any such representation from the action of $\wedge^k V$. Second, how to calculate the summand maps. This is done by Schur-Weyl duality, which says that every equivariant map from a tensor power of $V$ to another one is given by permuting the vectors.

Comment: @AsafShachar This implies that every equivariant map from tensor product of wedge powers to another is given by signed sums of permutations, where we sum enough terms to make the map antisymmetric and hence factor through the wedge power. The same thing works with symmetric powers an unsigned sums.