# Which polynomials in the minors of a matrix are invariant under conjugation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, polynomials, determinants, group-actions, invariant-theory

$\newcommand{\Cof}{\operatorname{cof}}$

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916471/which-polynomials-in-the-minors-of-a-matrix-are-invariant-under-conjugation).

Let $1<k<n$ be a fixed integer. I am trying to understand "what can be said" about the $k$-degree minors of a linear map $T:V \to V$, when $\dim V=n$.

Unlike the determinant, the $k$-minors are *not* invariant under conjugation. Thus we cannot associate an ordered sequence of minors to $T$, independently of the basis we choose for representing it. This raises the following question:

Consider the action of $\text{GL}(n)$ on $\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$ given by

$$ (M , A) \to \bigwedge^k M \circ A \circ \bigwedge^k M^{-1}.$$

After choosing a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can identify $\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n) $ with $\mathbb{R}^{\binom{n}{k}^2}$.

> Can we classify all the polynomials $P:\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$ which are invariant under the "conjugation-action" by $\text{GL}(n)$ described above?

Of course, every polynomial on $\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$ which is invariant under the conjugation action of $\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$
would be invariant under conjugation by the smaller subgroup which "comes from the copy of $\text{GL}(n)$ below".

[These $\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$
-invariant polynomials are classified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181237/the-stucture-of-invariant-polynomials-on-matrix).

For even $n$ and $k=\frac{n}{2}$, the determinant of an element $A \in \text{GL}(n)$ [can be expressed as a quadratic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#General_statement) in its $\frac{n}{2}$-minors. This polynomial is clearly $\text{GL}(n)$-invariant, but probably not $\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$-invariant. (Is there a nice way to see that it's not $\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$-invariant?).

I think this can be generalized: If $d | n$, the determinant of $A \in \text{GL}(n)$ can be expressed as a polynomial in its $\frac{n}{d}$-minors. This polynomial is clearly $\text{GL}(n)$-invariant, but probably not $\text{GL}(\bigwedge^{\frac{n}{d}} \mathbb{R}^n)$-invariant.

**Edit:**

Actually, there are more $\text{GL}(n)$-invariant polynomials; these are related to the [reconstruction of a matrix from its minors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303600/is-there-an-explicit-inversion-formula-for-the-exterior-algebra-functor). Here is an explicit special case:

Let $k=n-1$. Write $B=\Cof A$. Then $\Cof B=(\det A)^{n-2}A$ is a $\text{GL}(n)$-invariant polynomial of degree $n-1$. (It also holds that $\det(B)=(\det(A))^{n-1}$ and this allows (when $n$ is even) to recover $A$ in terms of $B$).

This can be generalized to whenever $k$ is relatively prime to $n$. (See, [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303600/is-there-an-explicit-inversion-formula-for-the-exterior-algebra-functor#comment756891_303600), and [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/304051/46290) for details).

This raises the following

> **Sub-question:** Except for the two examples mentioned above, 
>   are there any other $\text{GL}(n)$-invariant polynomials which are not $\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$-invariant?

Interestingly, both examples were related to the determinant. Perhaps this is not a coincidence-maybe all $\text{GL}(n)$-invariant polynomials of the $k$-minors are "factored" through the determinant in some way.

Comment: For the "starting point": it is possible to express the determinant of an element of $GL_4$ quadratically in terms of its $2$-minors. This isn't $GL(\wedge^2 \mathbb{R}^4)$-invariant, but obviously is $GL_4$-invariant.

Comment: I shouldn't say that it is $GL_4$-invariant; instead, it represents a class of $GL_4$ invariants. Of that class, at least one is necessarily $GL_4$-invariant, as $GL_4$ is reductive.

Comment: Thanks. I have some more questions now about what you wrote, I will appreciate your help: (1) I *think* that I see now what is wrong with the following explanation: We have a quadratic polynomial in $\binom{4}{2}^2$ variables, which have the following property: *When we apply* this polynomial to the $2$-minors of $4 \times 4$ matrix, it gives the determinant of that matrix. So, in some sense it is $GL_4$-invariant, when you only look at orbits in $\text{End}(\bigwedge^2 \mathbb{R}^4)$ which come from endomorphisms below. (only on orbits of $2$-minors...).

Comment: So, it is not necessarily true that this polynomial is $GL_4$-invariant "on the whole space" (when we do not constraint the variables to be minors of anything).  Is this the problem? (Do you see an argument showing that it isn't strictly $GL_4$-invariant?). (2) I am not sure what do you mean by a "class of $GL_4$-invariants. Can you elaborate on that? (My knowledge in representation theory is lacking, unfortunately). (3) How does $GL_4$ being reductive implies there is an element in the class which is really $GL_4$-invariant?

Comment: (4) Finally, I think this discussion made me realize I was asking the wrong question. I do not really care about the $GL_n$-invariance on the whole space of variables "$\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$"- I am only interested in polynomials which are conjugation-invariant *when restricted to the  $k$-minors of a matrix*-so from this perspective the quadratic polynomial which gives the determinant is legitimate. (So, I guess we now have two different questions, each might be interesting on its own). I will edit the question to emphasize this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: (1) is more an algebraic geometry thing than anything else. The ring of polynomials on a subvariety is a quotient of the whole space. So the ring of polynomials on the space of minors (i.e. numbers that follow Plucker relations) is a quotient of the ring of polynomials on $\wedge V$. And so you get a class, not just a single polynomial. (2) was bad phrasing on my part; I should have said "class of polynomials on $\wedge V$ that give the determinant on the subvariety". (3) is that reductive groups allow "averaging" - so take any polynomial that gives the det, and "average" it over an orbit.

Comment: @AsafShachar It seems you are looking at the following. If $V$ is a vector space then the ring of polynomials on $V$ is the symmetric algebra $\mathrm{Sym} V^*$ where $V^*$ is the dual of $V$. There is a natural linear map $\phi : V \to W$ with $V=\mathrm{End}(\mathbf{R}^n)$ and $W=\mathrm{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbf{R}^n)$. You are looking at the preimage of $(\mathrm{Sym} V^*)^{\mathrm{GL}_n}$ (which is known) under the canonical morphism $\mathrm{Sym} W^* \to \mathrm{Sym} V^*$. (...)

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Why is $\phi$ linear?

Comment: @user44191 you're right, $\phi $ is not linear but polynomial and homogeneous of degree $k$, sorry. So we have a linear map $\phi^* : W^* \to \mathrm{Sym}^k V^*$ which you can extend to the symmetric algebra of $W^*$.

Comment: The other point I wanted to make is about your subquestion. I'm not sure what is the quotient $W/\mathrm{GL}(n)$ but we know the dimension is at least $\dim W - n^2 = \begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}^2 - n^2$. On the other hand we know $W/\mathrm{GL}(\wedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$ has dimension $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k\end{pmatrix}$ as the link you mention shows. This means that there will be lot of polynomials which are $\mathrm{GL}(n)$-invariant but not $\mathrm{GL}$-invariant.